# ASP.NET MVC 5 customize user registration to connect to another database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, sql-server-2014

I'm pretty new to ASP.NET, specially to ASP.NET MVC, I'm currently needing to modify the registration process, by making that when a user registers succesfully, I make an INSERT into other tables on another database with the user email and username. So far I haven't found a way to achieve this specifically, since other things I have found is adding fields to register or changing data validation, that I currently don't need.

I have created a Stored Procedure that also does this, but I don't know which way is better.

IdentityModel.cs

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("UsersConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }

    public class ZivoyDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ZivoyDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ZivoyDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ZivoyDbContext();
        }
    }
```

And the Account Controller

```
// POST: /Account/Register
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);

                    //Insert into another table
                    ZivoyDbContext.Users.Add();

                    // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                    // Send an email with this link
                    // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                    // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                    // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                AddErrors(result);
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
```

I don't even know how to do this, please someone could explain me how this works? I have been searching about MVC 5 connecting to SQL Server, but almost all answers correspond to a single controller using a single connection, or using ADO.NET.

Comment: What's your actual question? What isn't working?

Comment: @Rik I don't know how to make a insert with user data into another table on another database, the code I tried doesn't do anything, I tried something I saw on another example. Where should I make the INSERT INTO... part?

Comment: Check this tutorial - I think it's EF6 - to see if it helps you get your data added: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/add-entity-using-dbcontext.aspx

Comment: @EtherDragon not quite what I need to do, since I think this should be more specific, I'm going to edit this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are trying to Add a User via the ZivoyDbContext, but not passing the User data into the method.

As long as the ZivoyDbContext database and tables have been created, use a call similar to this:

```
// Create a new User object using (all of the required) properties of the 
// new User you have just created via the Register method
ZivoyDbContext.Users.Add(new ApplicationUser
                {
                    UserName = user.UserName,
                    PasswordHash = user.Password,
                    Email = user.Email 
                }
);
```

Not forgetting to SaveChanges() if not automatically done in your context...

Remember, the IdentityDbContext has much that your run-of-the-mill EF context wouldn't.
Your context would likely have the Add, Update, Delete, Find methods etc. to keep the database up to date.
IdentityDbContext has a whole lot of stuff for managing Users and their Logins - your other database will most likely not need that if you just want to store a copy of the users there.
Having your context inherit from IdentityDbContext is a bit over the top if you are not using all of that functionality.